# Insertar un query en un dropdown

Tags: php, sql, php5, sql-server-2014

Lo que quiero hacer es que me traiga todas las sucursales que estan activa en ese momento de la consulta y salgan en un dropdown ligadas al id
Esta es mi consulta

```
SELECT * from CatTalleres where t_webpage = 1 AND T_habilitado =1
```

Que si, funciona y me trae varios datos pero solo quiero que me traiga las columnas

> T_Id y T_NombreCom

Estas dos ligas y se muestren en fila en el dropdown como seria implementar eso en el dropdown

Mi DropDown:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="codi">Centro</label>
                        <select id="Tcentro" name="Tcentro" class="form-control" required="">
                        <option selected>Escoge...</option>



          </select>
                      </div>
```

Tengo esto pero no me despliega los datos de la bd solo pinta el dropdown

```
  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="codi">Centro</label>
                        <select id="Tcentro" name="Tcentro class="form-control" required="">
                        <option selected>Escoge...</option>

                            <?php
                                    require('conexion.php');
                                    $sql ="SELECT T_Id, T_NombreCom from CatTalleres where t_webpage = 1 AND T_habilitado =1";
                                    $tstmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);   ?>


                                             <form action="insertCliente.php" method="post">
                                            <div>
                                       <label for="id">Centro</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="id" id="id"/>
                                        <select name="Centro">
                               <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['T_Id'].'">'.$row['T_NombreCom'].'</option>';
                        }?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Si entendí bien, lo que quieres es esto: `SELECT T_Id, T_NombreCom from CatTalleres where t_webpage = 1 AND T_habilitado =1`

Comment: Si, es correcto, solo faltaria como meter esos datos en el dropdown, gracias

Comment: Esa parte ya no la se... Esperemos a alguien más :-)

Comment: Revisa si te sirve [alguna respuesta de este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167960/php-populate-drop-down-list-with-sql-data)

Comment: Ese es todo el código que tienes? No me cuadran las etiquetas...

Comment: Es el codigo relevante para lo que quiero hacer

Comment: que es `$rows` no se supone que deberia ser el fetch de tu consultra, pues en tu codigo esta vacio, es msa ese foreach deberia fallar, ya que rows ni si quiera es un arrar.

Comment: lo otro, estas insertando un codigo de PHP + HTML (con forms y foto) dentro de las opciones de un select, hay varios problemas en tu codigo.

Comment: Quieres que en tu Select te despliegue una lista de tus sucursales activas con la consulta que te dio @AntonioVenerosoContreras?

Answer (score 0):

No deberías incluir en tu vista las consultas a la Base de Datos, sin embargo, en tu código tienes bastantes detalles, te falta incluir cualquier de los siguientes:
sqlsrv_fetch_array — Devuelve una fila como un array
sqlsrv_fetch_object — Devuelve la siguiente fila de datos de un conjunto resultado como un objeto
Aquí como emplearlo:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $tstmt , SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['T_Id'].'">'.$row['T_NombreCom'].'</option>';
}
```

Aquí puedes encontrar más información de los métodos.
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php

Disculpen si no puedo comentar, es que aún no cuento con los puntos. Soy nuevo pero quiero colaborar.

Saludos.

Comment: Por que no deberia incluir en la vista? y como lo harias tu ?

Comment: yo lo haría con MVC, el modelo te invocaría tu conexión, en el modelo traes los datos, se los pasas al controlador que se encarga de enviarlo a las vistas que requieras.

Answer (score -1):

El problema que tienes es que no has cerrado la etiqueta `<select>` tienes dos etiquetas `<select>` abiertas y solo una cerrada. Y además tienes las etiquetas `<select>` anidadas. espero te esea útil.

Comment: que etiqueta, puedes especificar?

Comment: <select> disculpa ya la edité

Comment: no entiendo como puede ser la respuesta correcta, si se ven muchos errores al menos en el codigo que comparte el usuario, no tan solo de la etiqueta select.

Comment: no se por qué el propietario la marcó como mejor respuesta, la verdad ahí hay muchos problemitas...

Answer (score -2):

Compañeros, con este script me fue posible hacerlo, gracias a todos.

```
       <?php
                            require('conexion.php');
                            $optins = '';
                            $filter=sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT T_Id, T_NombreCom from CatTalleres where t_webpage = 1 AND T_habilitado =1");
                            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($filter)){
                                $optins .="<option>".$row['T_Id'].$row['T_NombreCom']."</option>";
                            }

                    $menu="
                    <form id='filter' name='filter' method='POST' action='insertCliente.php'>
                    <p><label>Centro</label></p>
                    <select name ='filter' id='filter'>
                    ".$optins . "
                    </select>
                    </form>";
                    echo $menu;
                ?>
```